# Eclipse Ctrl+Shift+D not working With Pydev

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, pydev

When Using Pydev on Eclipse, I wanted to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> *Copy Lines* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to *Delete line*. But when I do so, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't work.

I [removed all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox51Y.png) the other bindings of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> but it doesn't work.

Fun fact, if I choose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it **does** work, so I'm wondering where is this key binding used.

The problem arrises only in Pydev, ie. when I open the file in *Text editor* the bindings work.

Comment: To be clear, when you state it "doesn't work" is the problem that you cannot add your binding for **Ctrl-Shift-D**, or that you can add the binding but it does not do anything? Put another way, if you go to **Window>Preferences>Keys**, then sort the **Binding** column, what do you see for the binding **Ctrl+Shift+D**? Updating your post with a screen shot of that would be very helpful.

Comment: One other thing to try is to remove the **Ctrl+Shift+C** binding(s) for **"Copy Lines"** to see whether that allows **Ctrl+Shift+D** to work. I doubt it, but it is very easy thing to try.

Comment: By *doesn't work* I mean, when I press **Ctrl+Shift+D** nothing happens, even if the shortcut is listed in the settings. Fun fact, I installed a html viewer and in the html files, the shortcut works. So yes, the binding exists but the function is not called.

Comment: I tried Ctrl+Shift+D alone (didn't work), then I tried Ctrl+Shift+C alone, works. Tried both, works only with Ctrl+Shift+C.

Comment: Okay, new infos ! The problem appears **only** when editing **Python files**, ie. the **PydevEditor**

Comment: So it sounds like you have some other binding(s) for **Ctrl+Shift+D**. If you go to **Window>Preferences>Keys**, then sort the **Binding** column, what do you see for the binding **Ctrl+Shift+D**? (In my case I see two entries: one for Edit and one for Run/Debug.)

Comment: When I do that, no other bindings for **Ctrl+Shift+D** si in the list :)

Comment: I uploaded an image, as you can see no other bindings for **Ctrl+Shift+D**, I also tried To write *Ctrl+Shift+D* or looked for any binding with *D* (there is only one: **Ctrl+D**: delete line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed for PyDev 6.3.3.

The problem was that there was a command bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which was not visible there because it wasn't properly categorized.

I fixed this in: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/422a0bde1d1a3ac5c091c00e88368a3bc3c0dc5f

Note that you could still override it if at the keybindings dialog you created a command and put the 'When' as 'PyDev editor scope' (which defines when it's active -- it wouldn't work without this because the hidden action had a higher priority given that its scope was narrower).

See details at: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/906